# Forward and inverse Gabor transform library in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, signal-processing

I am wondering if there exists a highly-optimized C/C++ library for both the *forward and inverse Gabor transforms* ([Wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabor_transform)).  This is **not** the same as the Gabor filter, which is normally applied to images.  The library can either be closed or FOSS/open-source, but I would prefer the latter since I am working on a research application.

I am implementing inverse Q filtering algorithms from the [Seismic Inverse Q filtering](http://www.scribd.com/doc/45448335/SEISMIC-INVERSE-q-FILTERING) book (see pg. 125).  The author appears to be fond of using the Gabor transform.

The forward and inverse transforms are required, since some operations are computed on the frequency-domain signals, and the inverse transform is used to compute a discrete time-domain signal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Up to my knowledge there is no specialized library to compute a Gabor transform (GT). Analogous to the continuous wavelet transform (CWT) the GT can only be approximated to a certain degree as it is defined as a time and frequency continuous function.

However, standard tools can be used to get a decent approximation of a GT. The usual way, similar to the CWT, is to implement those transforms in Fourier space. The GT as is the CWT are essentially just a filter bank. For a GT you would compute a FFT, multiply with the Fourier transform of the GT kernel, which is a gaussian centered at the desired frequency band, and then compute the inverse FFT for each band.

Another good approximation of the GT based on a IIR filterbank is described in [this article](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.19.7500). This method can also be implemented with standard tools (MatLab, SciPy, etc.)

I'm curious, what kind of scientific application are you aiming? Usually a CWT is the better choice, since it respects the natural scaling behavior and has a higher degree of symmetry, in particular it is invariant under dilations.

Comment: Thank you very much for your insightful answer. I've updated my question above to show the scientific application.  Is there an algorithm for the inverse Gabor transform as well?  I've downloaded the nice paper that you suggested, and I agree that the CWT is a good choice.

Comment: Moreover, there is also a C++/Java library for the CWT: http://sourceforge.net/projects/cwtlib/.  I can't tell from the source code if there is an inverse transform as well.  I don't think that this library has code for the inverse transform.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't seem that this library provides an inverse (most libs don't). But for the GT the inverse is just the sum over all frequency bands. For the CWT the same is true if your frequency bands are scaled logarithmically (if not you need to normalize appropriately).

Comment: @Bergner: Thanks, André.  I think that I understand this now.  A good reference for the inverse Short-Time Fourier transform (with Gaussian window, as this is the Gabor transform) is: J. B. Allen and L. R. Rabiner, “A unified approach to short-time Fourier analysis and synthesis,” Proceedings of the IEEE, vol. 65, no. 11, pp. 1558 – 1564, Nov. 1977.

Answer (score 1):

For 2022, there is a library toolbox [LTFAT](http://ltfat.org/) with matlab/octave/python interfaces and a c backend supporting 1D/2D forward and inverse gabor transform.